# Rails 3.1: associating project_id with new uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am uploading an image and want to associate it with the current project I'm in. I'm inside a project at the URL example.com/projects/1 and render this form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|%>
  <%= f.semantic_errors %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :image, :as => :file %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button :label => 'Upload Image', :button_html => { :class => "btn primary" } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've set in image.rb model, `belongs_to :project` and in project.rb model, `has_many :images`

My images_controller.rb create method looks like this:

```
def create
  image = params[:image]
  if user_signed_in?
    @image = Image.new(:title => image[:title],
                       :description => image[:description],
                       :user_id => current_user.id,
                       :project_id => params[:id])
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully uploaded an image"
    redirect_to project_path(params[:id]) and return
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error with image upload"
    redirect_to new_image_path and return
  end
 else
   redirect_to root_path
 end    
end
```

The image is created but fails to associate the image with the project_id. I know the problem is with `params[:id]` not pulling in the project_id, how do I pull the project id from the URL and associate it with the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your associations to create the new Image.

```
@image = Project.find(params[:id]).images.create(:title => image[:title],
                   :description => image[:description],
                   :user => current_user)
if @image.save...
```

if that does not work, please post the contents of your routes.rb and the url that is hit from the post request.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That did not work and I got the error "Couldn't find Project without an ID". POST url: Started POST "/images". In routes.rb I have both resources :images and resources :projects

Comment: That is why you are getting this error, the URL is wrong and does not contain the id parameter.  You need to pass it through, a hidden field is a relatively easy way to do this, another is to use Nested Resources.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thank you Gazler! I worked it out with a hidden field, sorry for the n00b question :)